# Swift generics: How to represent 'no type'?

Tags: swift, generics

I am using [Google's promises](https://github.com/google/promises) library, and I would like to create promise without any type (because I don't need any).

However, I am being forced to pick some type:

```
let promise = Promise<SomeType>.pending()
```

Is there a type I could pass in place of `SomeType` that would essentialy mean 'no type', when I need promises just for async flow and exception catching, but I don't want to return a specific value from a function?
For example, some type whose only valid value is `nil`?

I have encountered this problem in multiple places, the only workaround I found so far is to always provide a non-generic alternative, but it gets really tedious and leads to duplicate code.

Comment: If you want a Promise that will not return anything then you could use `Never`. https://nshipster.com/never/

Comment: I think this Q&A will be a bad use of time unless you tag with that library, or provide some cases that more of us would be familiar with. I'm thinking what Fogmeister said, or `Void`, but I can't tell if that's going to help you.

Comment: Never is the type with 0 valid values, so it can never be created. Void type has exactly 1 possible value, so that is used for things like making functions be procedures (not return any useful value, they return void)

Comment: Ah, I think @Shadowrun is correct here. You probably want Void rather than Never.

Comment: @Shadowrun Void is what I need, I had no idea how to Google for it :). Thank you! I'll be happy to pick your answer if you write it :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Types* are *sets of values*, like `Int` is the set of all integer numbers, `String` is the set of all sequences of characters and so on.

If you consider the number of items in the set, there are some special types with 0 items and 1 items exactly, and are useful in special cases like this.

`Never` is the type with no values in it. No instance of a `Never` type can be constructed because there are no values that it can be (just like an enum with no cases). That is useful to mark situations, code flow etc as 'can't happen', for example the compiler can know that a function that returns `Never`, can never return. Or that a function that takes `Never` can never be called. A function that returns `Result<Int, Never>` will never fail, but is in the world of functions returning `Result` types.  But because never can't be constructed it isn't what you want here. It would mean a Promise that can't be fulfilled.

`Void` is the type with exactly 1 value. It's normally spelled `()` on the left and `Void` on the right, of a function definition.  The value of a void is not interesting. It's useful to make a function that returns `Void` because those are like what other languages call subroutines or procedures. In this case it means a Promise that can be fulfilled but not with any value. It can only be useful for its side effects, therefore.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll add an example of use I needed: `function soSomethingAsync() -> Promise<Void> { ... return Promise<Void>(()) }`

Answer (score 0):

Is it a correct solution or a workaround if we create an empty class

class Default_Class : Codable {

}

and use this as Promise<Default_Class>.pending

Comment: I don't think this is necessary. You can use `Void` as the type.